# Find size of folders in an array using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of folders, called `$FolderArray`. It contains about 40 folders. Inside each folder are a bunch of `txt` files. I want to loop through each folder to get the number of files in each folder, as well as the total size of each folder. I got the number of files in each folder to work, but for the folder size, it ends up outputting the file size of the last file in each folder.

I pulled this out of a larger snippet of my code, so if anything needs more clarification please let me know. I appreciate the help!

```
$ProcessedLocation = "C:\Users\User.Name\Documents"
$FolderArray = gci -Path $ProcessedLocation | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

Foreach ($i in $FolderArray) 
{
    $FolderLocation = $ProcessedLocation + $i
    [int]$FilesInFolder = 0
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderLocation -Recurse -Include '*.txt' | % {
        $FilesInFolder = $FilesInFolder + 1
        $Length = $_.Length
        $FolderSize = $FolderSize + $Length
    }

    Write-Host $FolderSize

}
```

Comment: You loop over `$FolderArray` twice. Is `$FolderArray` an array of strings or objects (maybe show us how you populate/assign it in the first place)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I edited it to give more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over `$FolderArray` twice, once in the `foreach($i in $FolderArray)` loop, and then again inside the loop body:

```
foreach($i in $FolderArray){
    Get-ChildItem $FolderArray # don't do this
}
```

---

If you want to look into each folder in `$FolderArray` individually, reference the current variable (in your example that would be `$i`).

I would recommend saving the output from `Get-ChildItem` to a variable and then grab the size and count of the files from that:

```
# keep folders as DirectoryInfo objects rather than strings
$FolderArray = Get-ChildItem -Path $ProcessedLocation 

foreach ($Folder in $FolderArray) 
{
    # retrieve all *.txt files in $Folder
    $TxtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include '*.txt'

    # get the file count
    $FilesInFolder = $TxtFiles.Count

    # calculate folder size
    $FolderSize = ($TxtFiles | Measure -Sum Length).Sum

    # write folder size to host
    $FolderSizeMB = $FolderSize / 1MB
    Write-Host "$Folder is $FolderSizeMB MB in size"
}
```